# Issue with printf on CUDA GPU

Tags: c++, cuda, printf, gpu, nvidia

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define HOST __host__
#define DEVICE __device__

template<class L>
__global__ void launch_global (L f0) { f0(); }

template<typename T>
struct Array{
    T* __restrict__ data;

    DEVICE HOST inline
    T& operator()(int i)const noexcept {
        return data[i];
    }
};


int main(){

    int nx = 5;

    auto vec = Array<double>{new double[nx]};

    Array<double> *vec1;
    cudaMallocManaged((void**)&vec1, nx * sizeof(double));

    launch_global<<<1,256>>>([=] DEVICE () noexcept{
        int i = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;
        if(i < nx){
             (*vec1)(i) = 1.0;
             printf("Printing here %d %g\n", i,1.0);
        }
    });

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

return 0;
}
```

**Compilation:**

```
nvcc -x cu --expt-extended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr --expt-relaxed-constexpr kernel_test.cpp -o out
```

**Issue:**

The issue is that the print statement - printf("Printing here %d %g\n", i, 1.0), is not getting executed. But if I comment the previous line - vec(i)=1.0, then the print command executes. Could someone help me figure out why?

I also tried running with cuda-memcheck. There are no errors.

Comment: Shouldn't the body of the loop be `vec[i] = 1.0;`?

Comment: ```vec``` is of type ```Array``` which is a custom defined struct. It has an operator overloading of the parantheses. So ```vec(i)``` will return the data at ```data[i]```, where ```data``` is template-defined in the struct ```Array```.

Comment: I certainly get errors when running your code as posted with `compute-sanitizer`.  Perhaps your CUDA install is broken.

Comment: Thanks @RobertCrovella. I tried that now. I get the errors. That's definitely a lead. I have simplified the code and re-posted. Were you able to figure out what the issue is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various problems.

First of all, this:

```
auto vec = Array<double>{new double[nx]};
```

creates an allocated pointer by the use of `new`.  No matter what you subsequently do, that pointer ***will never be usable in device code***.  This isn't a proper strategy for using UM.

Next, your allocation size here make no sense:

```
cudaMallocManaged((void**)&vec1, nx * sizeof(double));
```

`vec1` is a pointer to something of type `Array<double>`.  Allocating a size based on `sizeof(double)` makes no sense.

If you want to do this using UM (managed memory), you will need to handle the allocation of the class object as well as the allocation of the embedded pointer in the object.

You generally appear to be confused that you are allocating an array of `Array<double>` objects, each of which has an embedded pointer to `double` items.  The following code has these issues fixed, and seems to run correctly for me:

```
$ cat t2239.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define HOST __host__
#define DEVICE __device__

template<class L>
__global__ void launch_global (L f0) { f0(); }

template<typename T>
struct Array{
    T* __restrict__ data;

    DEVICE HOST inline
    T& operator()(int i)const noexcept {
        return data[i];
    }
};


int main(){

    int nx = 5;

    Array<double> *vec;
    cudaMallocManaged((void**)&vec, sizeof(Array<double>));
    cudaMallocManaged((void**)&(vec[0].data), nx*sizeof(double));


    launch_global<<<1,256>>>([=] DEVICE () noexcept{
        for(int i = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x, stride = blockDim.x*gridDim.x;
             i < nx; i += stride){
             vec[0](i) = 1.0;
             printf("Printing here %d %g\n", i,1.0);
        }
    });

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t2239 t2239.cu  --extended-lambda -lineinfo
$ compute-sanitizer ./t2239
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
Printing here 0 1
Printing here 1 1
Printing here 2 1
Printing here 3 1
Printing here 4 1
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: That's terrific! Thank you so much, Robert!